# Multi-TF Volume Table (Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm making an indicator to calculate two EMAs, compare which one is greater, and then deliver the user a bias of bullish or bearish (by coloring the second row of a table). I've been able to do this successfully for a single TF, but the goal is to have it display the calculated bias for multiple TFs (specifically 6 [D1, H4, H1, M15, M5, M1) at once.

I'm trying to contain the calculations and table population within a function for easy reiteration and readability.

When compiling and running, it shows no errors, but for some reason nothing actually shows on the chart (even after I add it to the chart)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Code:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © tonemontgomery

//@version=5
indicator("MA Volume Bias", overlay = true)


src = input.source(defval = close, title= "Source", inline = "1", group = "EMA Settings")

len1 = input(defval = 25, title = "Period", inline = "2", group = "EMA Settings")
len2 = input(defval = 50, title = "", inline = "2", group = "EMA Settings")

color_bull = input.color(color.blue, "Bullish", group = "Table Settings")
color_bear = input.color(color.red, "Bearish", group = "Table Settings")

D1_show = input.bool(false, "Show D1 EMAs")
H4_show = input.bool(false, "Show H4 EMAs")
H1_show = input.bool(false, "Show H1 EMAs")
m15_show = input.bool(false, "Show M15 EMAs")
m5_show = input.bool(false, "Show M5 EMAs")
m1_show = input.bool(false, "Show M1 EMAs")


bias_table = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 6, rows = 2, frame_width 
= 1, frame_color = color.black, border_color = color.black,  border_width = 2, bgcolor = color.new(#9598a1, 84))

 
master_function(_TF, _column) =>
    data = request.security("", _TF, src)
    ema1 = ta.ema(data, len1)
    ema2 = ta.ema(data, len2)
    volume_bias = ema1 > ema2
    color_bias = volume_bias == true ? color_bull : color_bear
    if barstate.islast
        table.cell(table_id = bias_table, column = _column, row = 0, text = _TF, width = 3, height = 4, text_size = size.auto)
        table.cell(table_id = bias_table, column = _column, row = 1, text = "", width = 3, height = 4, bgcolor = color_bias)
    [color_bias, ema1, ema2]
    
    
master_function("D1", 0)
master_function("H4", 1)
master_function("H1", 2)
master_function("15", 3)
master_function("5", 4)
master_function("1", 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to the indicator name on the chart you would have had a red exclamation mark, if you click on it, it would display an error message explaining that the resolution was invalid.

Pine expects the different timeframe/resolution to be in a specific format. 1D, 2D, 240 (for H4) etc

````
master_function("1D", 0)
master_function("240", 1)
master_function("60", 2)
master_function("15", 3)
master_function("5", 4)
master_function("1", 5)```
````

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the TF resolutions, now I have one last problem it seems. The calculation for each EMA seems to change depending on the TF I'm on. When I switch TFs the biases change in my table, but the reason I used a security call was to pull from a specific TF for each EMA calculation, kind of isolating each calculations data. How can I fix this?

Comment: It has to be calculated within the context of the security call. As it is, len1/len2 are obtaining the value of `data` over a number of chart timeframe bars, not other timeframe's bars. For example `ema1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _TF, ta.ema(src, len1))` This ensures the ema is calculated correctly using `len1` number of timeframe bars

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough. Thank you so much.    